# How to select a whole column by its column name?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hey :) I have two subsheets. One with daily sales per product with dates in the first column and the header row contains the product id.

Now I want to use that information in my other sub-sheet to track the overall stock:
For example I had 1000 units of product xyz and want to track it like this:

`= 1000 - SUM('Daily Sales'!AW248:AW)` - this works perfectly, but it is not "bulletproof" ones the columns get realigned.

How can I change the formula, so that it searchs the right column and uses it as the argument?

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting the column with OFFSET and MATCH, to move as many columns as the header is find:

```
= 1000 - SUM(OFFSET('Daily Sales'!A248:A,0, MATCH("product id.",'Daily Sales'!1:1,0)))
```

I'm assuming the headers are in row 1:1, and the header is "product id.", Change if needed!